# In intellij idea what's the difference between Build and Rebuild artifact?

Tags: intellij-idea

There is an option to build artifact and to rebuild artifact, also clean artifact. So what build and rebuild artifact do and what's the difference between them?

Comment: Have you found your answer? I tried documentation but nothing comes up.

Answer (score 36):

Basically, "Build Artifact" is a conditional build, meaning it will only build if there is any modified code. If you haven't changed anything, it won't do anything.

"Rebuild Artifact", however, will force a build from scratch no matter if there are code changes or not.

From the horse's mouth: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206866915-understanding-build-vs-rebuild-vs-make-vs-compile

Answer (score 17):

From the [official documentation of IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-artifacts.html#artifact_build_options):

> **Build options (Build, Rebuild, etc.)**
>
> When building an artifact (Build | Build Artifacts), you have the following options:
>
> - Build. When used for the first time, the whole artifact is built. Each next time you use this option, only the part of the artifact affected by the changes you have made since the last build is built and added to the output folder.
> - Rebuild. Build the whole artifact as if for the first time. Technically, this is Clean followed by Build.
> - Clean. Delete all the contents of the artifact output directory.
> - Edit. Edit the artifact configuration.